# Reading Model data (Agile Toolkit)

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

I have a model which has some records. Now how can I get the records separately? (Without using CRUD or Grid).

Answer (score 1):

1. Models don't have records.
2. You have to start by reading documentation and tutorials about ATK4 class structure, models, views etc.
3. Also it's not clear what you mean by "get records separately"...

Answer (score 0):

Models in Agile Toolkit have been refactored into a stand-alone framework: Agile Data (http://git.io/ad)

The correct answer to the question on how to fetch the data from Models directly would be extensively covered in this document:

http://agile-data.readthedocs.io/en/develop/results.html